# Can "Unidentified Developer" be avoided with a webapp that generates OSX shell scripts?

Tags: macos, shell

I created a web app that allows users to enter an IP address to a printer, select the model and it creates a shell script that will download the print drivers, extract the print drivers, install the print drivers and create a print queue with 1 click.

The script works great except that users get a message that the script was created by an unidentified developer. I know you can go to the security settings to open away but some users don't know how to do that.

How do i identify my app or make it so that its not considered an unidentified developer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least, not without significant changes to your workflow.

Normally, this warning can be bypassed by [signing your application with an Apple Developer ID certificate](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/). (Note that this requires a paid Apple Developer Program membership.)

However, this signature can only be applied to an `.app` bundle. It cannot be applied to a standalone shell script. And even if you bundled your script in an application, you'd have to sign every one of those applications separately.

Comment: Hmm. Does the name of the app bundle impact the signature? I'm wondering if you could have perhaps one signed copy per driver, and then fold the address into the "file" (.app directory) name.

Comment: That could work, if there's little enough information that it'll fit in the filename. You'll need to be aware of standard transformations made by web browers, though, like appending "(1)" to duplicate downloads.

Comment: i have to totally recreate my web app then. Any idea's on how i should do it? Another company made something similiar but i have no idea how they did it --> https://www.printerlogic.com/